Support std::hex in custom operator<<
I have written my own operator<< implementation in my Logger class:
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Logger
{
public:

    enum Severity
    {
        INFORMATION = 0,
        WARNING = 1,
        ERROR = 2
    };

    Logger( std::ostream &os, Logger::Severity severity )
    : outputStream( os ), loggerSeverity( severity ) {}

    const std::vector<std::string>& getLogLines() const { return logLines; }

    friend Logger& operator<<( Logger &logger, Logger::Severity severity ) {
        logger.currentSeverity = severity;
        logger.outputStream << logger.severityMap.find( severity )->second << ": ";
        return logger;
    }

    friend Logger& operator<<( Logger &logger, const char *logLine ) {
        if( logger.currentSeverity >= logger.loggerSeverity )
        {
            logger.logLines.push_back( logLine );
            logger.outputStream << logLine;
        }
        return logger;
    }

private:
    std::ostream &outputStream;
    Logger::Severity loggerSeverity;
    std::vector<std::string> logLines;
    Logger::Severity currentSeverity;
    const std::map<Logger::Severity, std::string> severityMap =
    {
        { Logger::Severity::INFORMATION, "<INF>" },
        { Logger::Severity::WARNING, "<WARN>" },
        { Logger::Severity::ERROR, "<ERR>" }
    };
};

now I am wondering how I can supoprt std::hex formatting? I would like to be able to call my logger like this:
logger << Logger::Severity::ERROR << "CRC mismatch ( expected 0x" << std::hex << record->metaData.crc << " but got 0x" << std::hex << crc32 << std::dec << " )" << "\n";

but I get:
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘Logger’ and ‘std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)’)
   79 |         logger << Logger::Severity::ERROR << "CRC mismatch ( expected 0x" << std::hex << record->metaData.crc << " but got 0x" << std::hex << crc32 << std::dec << " )" << "\n";
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
      |                                           |                                       |
      |                                           Logger                                  std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&)


please do not strip off includes from the code. Please post a [mcve]. If the code one has to write to get yours to compile is more than what needs to be written for an answer, the motivation to write an answer drops

Please provide enough code to reproduce issue. We should be able to just copy paste this and reproduce this without modification.

std::hex is a function. You need to write the corresponding overload. Try std::endl too, its a fucntion template.

you added some, but there are still missing. You can try to compile the code before posting it here.

Off topic: this style of loggers are out of fashion/outdated. fmt based are much more handy. Also it is better to use ready solutions then crafting it by yourself. I recommend spdlog..

logger.outputStream << logger.severityMap.find( severity )->second << ": "; isn't how you're supposed to use the overload.

@user12002570 What is your recommendation?

This logger has lots of issues (it will fail miserably in case of multiple threads - and logger must be thread safe).

@MarekR I mean I started it literally 1h ago, I didn't expect it to be thread safe.

How does std::ostream do it?
std::hex is a function "manipulator" with signature std::ios_base& hex( std::ios_base& str ); (CPP Reference).
And std::ostream has an overload for "outputting" functions like this:
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
You can define your own operator << for this type that just passes it along to the underlying stream.
If you wanted to handle it yourself, you would need something of type std::ios_base you could give the manipulator as argument and it will do the equivalent of .setf(std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield) on it.
Or you would have to invent your own manipulators and not use the std one.

Just pass I/O manipulators along to the underlying stream:
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger &logger,
                          std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&))
{
    logger.outputStream << func;
    return logger;
}

